# Carregar foto do Datagridview e passar para picturebox C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, wpf

Galera to com pouco de dificuldade em pegar minha foto cadastrada e mostrar ela no PictureBox

Meu cenário é o seguinte:

Tenho um Form de cadastro que faz a inserção dos dados e
Um Form que faz a pesquisa do cadastro que é apresentado em um DataGridView;
Pois bem eu faço a inserção dos dados e da foto convertida para binário, utilizando o db sqlserverm ais to com dificuldade em passar a foto para minha picture, os demais campos eu consigo trazer, mas a foto não.

Obs: é minha primeira vez que to trabalhando com foto no WindowsForms.

segue meu código galera.

<-- Esse é do meu DataGridView onde seleciono a célula jogando os dados para o form de cadastro-->

```
private void dgw_Onibus_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (lblOperacao.Text == "Aluno Master")
            {

                DataGridViewRow dr = dgw_Onibus.SelectedRows[0];
                this.Hide();
                cg.ds = new DataSet();
                FRM_CadOnibusCircular frm = new FRM_CadOnibusCircular();
                frm.Show();

                frm.TB_id.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                frm.TB_IdFicha.Text = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                frm.TB_NomeUser.Text = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                frm.MK_TelUser.Text = dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                frm.TB_RgUser.Text = dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                frm.MTK_CpfUser.Text = dr.Cells[5].Value.ToString();

                frm.TB_NomeProprietario.Text = dr.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                frm.MK_TelProprietario.Text = dr.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                frm.TB_EnderecoProprietario.Text = dr.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                frm.TB_QdProprietario.Text = dr.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                frm.TB_EmailProprietario.Text = dr.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
                frm.TB_RgProprietario.Text = dr.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
                frm.MKT_Proprietario.Text = dr.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
                frm.TB_NumeroProprietario.Text = dr.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
                frm.TB_LoteProprietario.Text = dr.Cells[15].Value.ToString();

                bool proprietarioChecked = dgw_Onibus.CurrentRow.Cells["opcao"].Value.ToString().Contains("Proprietario");
                bool depedenteChecked = dgw_Onibus.CurrentRow.Cells["Opcao"].Value.ToString().Contains("Depedente");
                bool colaboradorChecked = dgw_Onibus.CurrentRow.Cells["opcao"].Value.ToString().Contains("Colaborador"); // Ou contém "Yoga", não sei como você guarda isto na sua `DataGridView`

                // Obter checkBoxlist da seleção

                int indexCbProprietario = GetItemIndex(frm.CLB_Opcao, "Proprietario");
                int indexCbDepedente = GetItemIndex(frm.CLB_Opcao, "Depedente");
                int indexCbColaborador = GetItemIndex(frm.CLB_Opcao, "Colaborador"); // fmr.chekedListBox é o nome do seu CheckedListBox dentro do seu form. 

                //Pegar o valor da dataGridView que diz se a determinada atividade está marcada





                // Checar o valor da Opcao no seu `checkedListBox`
                frm.CLB_Opcao.SetItemChecked(indexCbProprietario, proprietarioChecked);
                frm.CLB_Opcao.SetItemChecked(indexCbDepedente, depedenteChecked);
                frm.CLB_Opcao.SetItemChecked(indexCbColaborador, colaboradorChecked);



                frm.BT_UpdateOnibus.Enabled = true;
                frm.BT_DeleteOnibus.Enabled = true;
                frm.BT_SaveOnibus.Enabled = false;
                frm.Lbl_Usuario.Text = lblUsuario.Text;
                lblOperacao.Text = "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(erro.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

já tentei dessa forma mais nao deu certo!

```
frm.picFoto.Image = null;

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[linhaNumero][6] != System.DBNull.Value)
                {
                    foto_array = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[linhaNumero][6];
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(foto_array);
                    frm.picFoto.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                }

 int linhaNumero = 0;
    byte[] foto_array;
```

Obs:"minha coluna da tabela onde armazena a foto, ela esta definida como image, inicialmente tinha deixado como Varbinary, mais mudei para testes."
desde de já agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Olá Lucas, o que não deu certo? algum erro? seu código parece ok, converte para array de bytes, põe num Stream para depois usar o `Image.FromStream`, está certo

Comment: me retorna o erro de "cannot fild table0" quando clico na celula do datagridview para jogar a foto no form de cadastro para realizar o update etc...